# Reduce (1024x768 32bpp) image size to 30-50 k?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, compression

I' m taking a screenshot via Robot, BufferedImage's size 180-200kb (1024x768 px,32bpp).
I make Standard jpeg compress(with 0.4f quality) and it's size reduces to 75-85kb . 
I want to reduce image size to 30-50 kb int 150-250 miliseconds.Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 2):

You might try another image compression algorithm, like JPEG 2000 etc. 
Speed depends on your system's capabilities as well, whereas compression rate also depends on your image data.

Comment: i tried jp2000 in jai, compression speed was very slow and compressed image size same as jpeg(maybe i couldnt make correct configuration),
I looked at jj2000 library but their site(http://jpeg2000.epfl.ch/) not working, so i cant find documentation&usage and cant use it.
Thanks for answer

Comment: @gulteking Try this link: http://code.google.com/p/jj2000/ - Additionally, can you give some more information on the timings and your system?

Comment: 3GB RAM, CORE 2 DUO T6500 2.1 GHZ CPU, Ati Radeon HD 4330 Graphics Card, Timing : 900-1200 miliseconds.
I think I used jai code wrong(code is here: http://pastebin.com/gL9YwXXQ) . I tried jj2000 but i couldn't find documentation. Would you give me some sample code about jj2000 usage

Answer (score 0):

You can take at look at the [Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) API](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) to reduce the processing time, but I'm not sure if this image size is possible for the other constraints.

Reference [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Advanced_Imaging):

> While the API is provided in Java, platform-specific implementations can either use the pure Java implementation or provide an implementation that takes advantage of native technology on the platform to provide better performance.

Comment: i tried jp2000 in jai, compression speed was very slow and compressed image size same as jpeg(maybe i couldnt make correct configuration)
Thanks for Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing resolution of image too.

Comment: i tried change resolution to 800x600, when i convert it back to original resolution, image quality became awesome

Comment: So you need the original resolution?